# Paginação com Filtros usando CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho uma consulta com filtros vindo de um formulário. A consulta é executada corretamente, o cálculo de páginas também. O formulário envia via método `$_POST`.

Ao navegar entre as páginas geradas pelo resultado, como a paginação é enviada via `$_GET` e os parâmetros via `$_POST`, está dando erro para exibir os resultados a partir da página 2.

Gostaria de saber uma boa forma da paginação no `CodeIgniter` para resolver essa questão e passar os parâmetros ao selecionar o número da página.

Comment: quais parametros vc enviar via post? os filtros?

Comment: sim os dados do formulário. fiz usando sessão.

Comment: Posta o que de código